# missed interrupts unless you use Thread.interrupted()?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a question about the following example from the Java tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html

```
for (int i = 0; i < importantInfo.length; i++) {
    // Pause for 4 seconds
    try {
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // We've been interrupted: no more messages.
        return;
    }
    // Print a message
    System.out.println(importantInfo[i]);
}
```

The Java tutorial seems to suggest that this will handle exceptions fine, because most of the execution time will be spent in Thread.sleep() which throws InterruptedException if the thread receives an interrupt.

However, couldn't this example miss an interruption completely if it is received when the code is executing `println`? As such wouldn't it be safest to modify it like the following (adding another call to Thread.interrupted())?

```
for (int i = 0; i < importantInfo.length; i++) {
    // Pause for 4 seconds
    try {
        if (Thread.interrupted()){
            throw new InterruptedException()
        }
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // We've been interrupted: no more messages.
        return;
    }
    // Print a message
    System.out.println(importantInfo[i]);
}
```

But really if that's the case, we could never rely on InterruptedException to be helpful, unless we were OK with it missing sometimes, or if we interrupted Threads in a loop or something. What am I missing?

Comment: The thread is flagged as interrupted so on the next iteration `sleep()` would throw the InterruptedException (unless the thread's interrupted flag was reset).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Interrupting a thread sets a flag, which is checked next time `Thread.sleep(...)` is invoked.

So, even if it's not in the `Thread.sleep` when the interrupt occurs, the interruption is not lost.

---

An important thing to do is to re-interrupt the thread when you catch `InterruptedException`:

```
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  Thread.currentThread().interrupt();

  // ...
}
```

This allows code outside this method to know that the reason this method finished early was because of interruption; and it should handle the interruption too. This may not matter if the `run()` method is being executed directly by a `Thread`; but this is not the only way in which that method may be run.

---

Incidentally, a cleaner way to write that code is to catch the interruption outside the loop:

```
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < importantInfo.length; i++) {
        // Pause for 4 seconds
        Thread.sleep(4000);

        // Print a message
        System.out.println(importantInfo[i]);
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // We've been interrupted: no more messages.
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

I find that it is clearer to do it outside, because it shows clearly that *interruption stops the loop iteration*.

Comment: Not sure about cleaner, but it is the only correct way if you're not in the `run()` method (which the tutorial is).

Comment: @shmosel the "cleaner" is really referring to the catch-outside-the-loop.

Comment: @shmosel I've separated the two things now.

Comment: Interesting, so do `Thread.sleep()`, `join()`, etc just use `Thread.interrupted()` to determine whether to throw the InterruptedException?

Comment: Logically, yes. But that might not be how it is actually implemented (e.g. they are native methods, and call the native equivalent).